# Which Deadshot is closer to the comic book original: the one from the DCEU or the one from the Arrowverse?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, arrowverse, comic-adaptation, arrow, suicide-squad

In the *Suicide Squad* movie (2016), Will Smith's portrayal of Floyd Lawton is that of a man with a code and principles who, deep down, is good and will only kill other bad people. On the other hand, *Arrow*'s portrayal of Floyd Lawton is more of a true villain, a psychopathic killer who uses more inhumane means and seemingly enjoys killing.

Which portrayal is more true to the original comic book Deadshot?